# How to edit the toggle-effect in jquerys' toggle-function?

Tags: jquery

I use jquerys' toggle-function to hide/show a block of my markup by updating display to none or block, like this:

```
$("#trigger").click(function () {
    $("#target").toggle("linear", function() {
  });
});
```

jquery thankfully adds me an effect to that by default, but I would like to edit this one to fade it in or make it slide in from top to bottom or whatever. I already have edited the param **linear**, but this changes nothing. What do I need to do?

Comment: Have you considered using `fadeToggle()` or `slideToggle()`? Or are you aiming for a "composite" effect?

Comment: if nor `fadeToggle()` neither `sliderToggle()` meets your wanted effect you need to make an `animate()` and `toggle()` combination

Comment: If you want a custom toggle, try chaining animate() and toggle() together

Comment: Fully hit me in the face ;) slideToggle() made the job wonderfully. Thank you!